# Using Cloudformation for Codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I am trying to use troposphere to make a cloudformation template.  The stack the template makes intended to be a simple example of codedeploy

I have previously got troposphere to generate ec2, s3, iam and route53 generating templates.  I have previously made codedeploy work with the GUI AWS Console

I am encountering an error and I don't see why

Here is my troposphere program

```
    from troposphere import Template
    from troposphere.codedeploy import Application, DeploymentConfig, DeploymentGroup, MinimumHealthyHosts, S3Location


    #1
    #CreateApplication with an applicationName
    app=Application( 'test123')

    #2
    #CreateDeploymentConfig

    config=DeploymentConfig('config123',
                           MinimumHealthyHosts=MinimumHealthyHosts( Type='HOST_COUNT', Value=1 )
                           )

    #3
    #CreateDeploymentGroup using applicationName as input
    #and deploymentConfigName
    depgroup=DeploymentGroup("depgroup123",
                             ApplicationName='test123',
                             DeploymentConfigName='config123', 
                             ServiceRoleArn='arn:aws:iam::930517348825:role/isCompatibleWithAWSCodeDeploy')
)    
    t = Template()
    t.add_description(
    """
    Test of making a code deploy setup from a template
    """)
    t.add_resource(app)
    t.add_resource(config)
    t.add_resource(depgroup)

    print(t.to_json())
```

Here is the Cloudformation template it makes

```
{
    "Description": "\nTest of making a code deploy setup from a template\n",
    "Resources": {
        "config123": {
            "Properties": {
                "MinimumHealthyHosts": {
                    "Type": "HOST_COUNT",
                    "Value": 1
                }
            },
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig"
        },
        "depgroup123": {
            "Properties": {
                "ApplicationName": "test123",
                "DeploymentConfigName": "config123",
                "ServiceRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::930517348825:role/isCompatibleWithAWSCodeDeploy"
            },
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup"
        },
        "test123": {
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::Application"
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the template into the cloudformation GUI this occurs before roll back

```
09:08:50 UTC+0000   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig   config123   Resource creation cancelled
09:08:48 UTC+0000   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig   config123   
09:08:48 UTC+0000   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup    depgroup123     No application found for name: test123
09:08:47 UTC+0000   CREATE_COMPLETE     AWS::CodeDeploy::Application    test123
```

What I don't understand is that the stack has created the AWS::CodeDeploy::Application "test123" but then the next message says "No application found for name: test123"

role/isCompatibleWithAWSCodeDeploy already exists.
Do I need to add anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

just use [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)s:

```
            "ApplicationName": {"Ref": "test123"},                                                                                                                                                        
            "DeploymentConfigName": {"Ref": "config123"},
```

### Detailed answer

From what I can see from you cf template, the created application doesn't have name. In order for it to have a name the appropriate piece of your cf template should look like this:

```
    "test123": {                                                                                                                                                                                          
        "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::Application",
        "Properties" : {
            "ApplicationName" : "test123"
        }                                                                                                                                                           
    }
```

The same applyes to config. The config should have `DeploymentConfigName` property.
But even after adding ApplicationName launching may fail. Because your template doesn't guarantee that depgroup is created after application and deploymentconfig.

To guarantee correct order of creation you should use [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)s:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    "Description": "\nTest of making a code deploy setup from a template\n",                                                                                                                                  
    "Resources": {                                                                                                                                                                                            
        "config123": {                                                                                                                                                                                        
            "Properties": {                                                                                                                                                                                   
                "MinimumHealthyHosts": {                                                                                                                                                                      
                    "Type": "HOST_COUNT",                                                                                                                                                                     
                    "Value": 1                                                                                                                                                                                
                }                                                                                                                                                                                             
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig"                                                                                                                                                       
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "depgroup123": {                                                                                                                                                                                      
            "Properties": {                                                                                                                                                                                   
                "ApplicationName": {"Ref": "test123"},                                                                                                                                                        
                "DeploymentConfigName": {"Ref": "config123"},                                                                                                                                                 
                "ServiceRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::930517348825:role/isCompatibleWithAWSCodeDeploy"                                                                                                                     
            },                                                                                                                                                                                                
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup"                                                                                                                                                        
        },                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        "test123": {                                                                                                                                                                                          
            "Type": "AWS::CodeDeploy::Application"                                                                                                                                                            
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: ApplicationName was missing as a prop for "Application" in the version of troposphere I had.  Latest from git fixes this

Comment: Most useful answer, thanks v much.   Now trying to figure out if CodeDeploy does fully work with CloudFormation.  ``AWS::CodeDeploy::Deployment`` seems to be be missing or undocumented